# Set nominal time to run the oozie coordinator daily in HUE

Tags: hadoop2, oozie, hue

I am trying to set SLA for my oozie coordinator but nominal_time always stays on the day when i submitted the coordinator.

SLA Details:
  Nominal Time - Thu Dec 05 15:45:00 UTC 2019
  Actual Start Time - Sat Dec 07 07:45:00 UTC 2019
  Expected End Time - Thu Dec 05 16:05:00 UTC 2019
  Expected Duration (in mins) - 45
  Actual Duration (in mins) - -1

How do i increase nominal_time by a day to match it with actual_time ?

Answer (score 0):

I could fix it by passing ${coord:nominalTime()} in nominal_time.

[image]